# Можно ли как-то открыть картинку на странице в PhotoSwipe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На странице есть картинка при клике на которую она должна открыться на весь экран, возможно ли такое реализовать с PhotoSwipe? В документации ничего похожего не увидел.

Если с PhotoSwipe так сделать не получится, у него есть какие-нибудь достойные аналоги?

Comment: Подробнее расскажите что Вы хотите получить

Comment: У меня на html странице есть картинка в тебе <img />. Мне нужно чтобы при клике на эту картинку она открывалась в PhotoSwipe, т.е. на весь экран и со всеми фишками этого плагина. Вот как-то так)

Comment: в документации http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html пункт Step 3: initialize. Там пример

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то надо заменить "items", верно? А как туда <img /> запихать?

Comment: Посмотрите ответ

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий пример для Вашей задачи (в первую очередь смотрите JS) :

```js
var openPhotoSwipe = function() {
    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

    //Указываем изображения и размеры
    var items = [
        {
            src: 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg',
            w: 964,
            h: 1024
        },
        {
            src: 'https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg',
            w: 1024,
            h: 683
        }
    ];
  
    //Настройки
    var options = {       
       history: false,
       focus: false,
        showAnimationDuration: 0,
        hideAnimationDuration: 0
    };
    
    //инициализируем галерею
    var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
    gallery.init();
};
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = openPhotoSwipe;
```

```html
<link href="http://photoswipe.s3.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://photoswipe.s3.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Open PhotoSwipe</button>

<div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="pswp__bg"></div>
    <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">
        <div class="pswp__container">
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">
            <div class="pswp__top-bar">
                <div class="pswp__counter"></div>
                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>
                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button>
                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>
                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>
                <div class="pswp__preloader">
                    <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
                      <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
                        <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
                <div class="pswp__share-tooltip"></div> 
            </div>
            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)">
            </button>
            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)">
            </button>
            <div class="pswp__caption">
                <div class="pswp__caption__center"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```